# Poner dentro de un condicional un input en python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Buenos dias/tardes/noches mi pregunta es la siguiente, soy nuevo en esto.
Como podria poner dentro de un condicional un input? especificamente, necesito que se ingrese un dato tipo int, pero tambien quiero que si se ingresa un float, que imprima en pantalla: "el numero ingresado es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen días, puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma.

```
while True: 
    try:
        num = int(input("Ingresa un número: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No es un número válido")
```

Comment: Solución elegante, muchas  gracias.

Comment: aunque soy nuevo :( no conocia el comando break ni except.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. ¿Cómo podría poner dentro de un condicional un input?

```py
# Ciclo que lee un entero hasta que este es el número 0
while (entrada := int(input())) != 0:
    print(entrada)
```

El operador [walrus](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**(:=)** disponible a partir de [python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), permite asignar valores a variables como parte de una expresión, esto es realmente útil cuando se obtiene un input que forma parte de la condición y que ademas es utilizado en el cuerpo de la sentencia que hace uso de la condición, en este caso, el while.

> ¿Es útil para tu caso en concreto poner el input dentro de un condicional?

No, realmente lo único que estas intentado validar es si tu entrada es un número entero, si en cambio estuvieramos validando que tu entrada fuera un número entero vaĺido **y** se quisiera comprobar una condición como que el número es distinto de 0, entonces tu programa podría beneficiarse del operador walrus. En el ejemplo estoy considerando que el ciclo se deberá romper cuando se ingrese una entrada no válida, es decir, una entrada que no es un número entero.

```py
try:
    while (entrada := int(input("Número: "))) != 0:
        print(entrada)
except ValueError:
    print("La entrada no es un número entero válido")
```

Si tu código requiere que aún cuando se ha ingresado una entrada invalida se continue el ciclo, entonces debes tomar otro enfoque más tradicional sin el uso del operador walrus.

```py
while True: 
    try:
        entrada = int(input("Número: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("La entrada no es un número entero válido pero aún así continua con el ciclo")
```

Comment: no me queda del todo claro el operador walrus, pero se ve interesante y no lo conocia

Comment: Gracias, no conocia el operador walrus, pero ahora veo que puedo explotarlo mejor, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción, esta vez sin usar `try / except`, sería usar el método `isdigit()` de las cadenas de texto y comprobar también el caso de que el número sea negativo y por tanto empiece con el signo `-`.

```
    print("Por favor, introduce un número entero")
    while True:
        entrada = input()
        if entrada.isdigit() or (
            entrada.startswith("-") and 
            entrada[1:].isdigit()
        ):
            entero = int(entrada)
            break
        print("Debe introducirse un número entero")
    
    # Y aqui ya usariamos el entero para lo que sea
    print("El numero introducido fue {}".format(entero))
```